# Why I cant render "Hello" from function in my jsx?

Tags: reactjs

I need to render some html when element is clicked, it is very simple stuff, but I am new to React so help anyone. I have this func which is returning some jsx, and I wont to render it on click event.

In this example I should get "Hello" under the li with a class of link,

here is my code;

```
const returnSomething = () => {
        return (
            <h1>Hello</h1>
        );
    };

    return (
        <div>
            <div>
                <ul>

                </ul>
                <ul>
                    <li className="link" onClick={() => returnSomething()}>Selector</li>
                    { returnSomething }
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
```

Comment: You are returning a function. You need to return the result of the execution of that function. Also, your onClick does not do what you think it does. Have a look at some React tutorials for conditional rendering.

Comment: I am returning h1 element  from func, and I wont to show that h1 under li of class name link, simple as that!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several problems with your code.

You have a function that returns some JSX:

```
const returnSomething = () => {
  return <h1>Hello</h1>
}
```

And you are calling it using the `onClick` handler:

```
<li className="link" onClick={() => returnSomething()}>
```

That doesn't do anything. All you are doing is executing the function, but the JSX gets returned inside the `onClick` handler:

```
onClick={() => // JSX gets returned here
  returnSomething()}>
```

Which means nothing happens with the JSX you are returning. It doesn't get rendered because it's returned to the `onClick`.

Then you also write the following code:

```
{ returnSomething }
```

But you are not executing the function, so you are trying to return the actual function object inside JSX. That won't render the result of the function.

Also, the `onClick` handler is not connected to the function you are returning.

What I mean is that this:

```
onClick={() => returnSomething()}>
```

is not related to this:

```
{ returnSomething }
```

They are not connected. So executing `returnSomething` inside `onClick` does not effect the `returnSomething` that you are returning.

---

To conditionally render something, you need to use state. The `onClick` should set the state, for example:

For example:

```
const Component = () => {
    const [isTextVisible, setIsTextVisible] = useState(false)

    return (
        <div>
            <div>
                <ul></ul>
                <ul>
                    <li className="link" onClick={() => setIsTextVisible(true)}>
                        Selector
                    </li>
                    {isTextVisible && <h1>Hello</h1>}
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}
```

Initially the `isTextVisible` value is `false`, so the `h1` will not render. But when you click the `li`, the `onClick` handler calls `setIsTextVisible(true)`, which means that now `isTextVisible` is `true`, and therefore the `h1` tag renders.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
const [show, setState] = useState(false);
const returnSomething = () => {
    if (show) {
      return <h1>Heelo</h1>;
    }
    return null;
  };

<div onClick={() => setState(!show)}>Click here {returnSomething()}</div>
```

Comment: But that way it would always be visible, I wont to show it only after click event

Comment: You need to keep some state for that, either using a class component or using the `useState` hook in a function component.

Comment: update answer [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/sparkling-voice-q46eq)

Answer (score 0):

You need to use state to accomplish what you want (only rendering markup if the button has been clicked).

```
function App() {

const returnSomething = () => <h1>Hello</h1>
const [isVisible, setIsVisible] = React.useState(false)

    return (
        <div>
            <div>
                <ul>

                </ul>
                <ul>
                    <li className="link" onClick={() => setVisible(true)}>Selector</li>
                    { isVisible && returnSomething() }
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

May be add based on state variable, you could show on click

```
import React from "react";

export default class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { showText: false };
  }

  setText = () => {
    this.setState({ showText: true });
  };

  returnSomething = () => <h1>Hello</h1>;

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <div>
          <ul />
          <ul>
            <li className="link" onClick={this.setText}>
              Selector
            </li>
            {this.state.showText && this.renderSomething}
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```